# Can't sudo after lock password, can I recover from that?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, login, password

After setup ubuntu with default settings, It allows user to login with password, so I use passwd -l [username] to forbid password login both in ssh and console.

But when I use sudo to execute commands, it needs password so I can't use sudo any more.

Is there any solution that I can use sudo again, another question is how to forbid password login both in ssh and console but keep sudo password auth available?

Comment: why would you forbid password login? what's the motivation?

Comment: More security. System only allows ssh private key login.

Comment: What if your SSH daemon fails? Then you're screwed, as you are right now. The correct solution is to disallow SSH passwords but still allow console logins.

Comment: What better security is there than that? _No one_ can get in.

Comment: Just forbid password login, only allow ssh private key login.

Comment: If you are using PAM, I believe there is a module that requires root login, i.e. disallows login for anybody else - just put it into PAM configuration for `login` and you are sure, that if a regular user gets physical access to the machine he won't get anywhere without a root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could boot up in single user mode to get a root console.  You could then mount your filesystem, and fix the affected account.

(This is assuming grub hasn't been password locked also ..., you hold down shift during boot to bring up grub, and add 'single' to the boot statement after the word 'splash' )

As for best practice, I agree with strugee's comment.

- Just remembered- Ubuntu has that 'recovery mode' grub option, so you may not even have to edit your boot command...

Comment: yes, I just use recover mode, login as root, remount root partition and get recovered. But is it possible to recover without physical access?

Comment: @elprup Only if you have `PermitRootLogin yes` in your `sshd_config`. Or if you have a known unpatched vulnerability on your system. :)

Comment: @peterph - I think you would also have had to enable root account login (sudo passwd), it's disabled in it's default state in ubuntu.

Comment: @elprup You configured your system to prevent any method from logging in as root. So no, unless you can access it from the outside or you have a vulnerable application running, you can't log in as root.